# Codeigniter Restserver basic autentication always valid

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I've a problem with Codeigniter Restserver (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) because I've enabled basic autentication but it returns always results even if credentials are wrong.
See details below:

Into rest.php file I modified the value:
*$config['rest_auth'] = '';*
to
*$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';*

then

*$config['auth_source'] = 'ldap';*
to
*$config['auth_source'] = '';*

Credentials are stored in *$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'];*

But if I try to call my webservice, it answers with results even if credentials are wrong or missed.
Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Without having a look at your whole application, this can be difficult to diagnose... I suggest you set a breakpoint in the `_auth_override_check` method of the `REST_Controller` class, there might be some overrides to authentication for some reason. Otherwise, I'd have a good look at which hooks are called during REST calls.

Comment: Maybe there is an errore in 3.0.0 version because with 2.8.0 it works fine. I informed the developer.